# B&R Automation Studio "Error 9340: Project contains Visual Component objects but no version definition"

Tags: structured-text, br-automation-studio

When compiling an B&R project in Automation Studio this error is thrown.

```
Error 9340: Project contains Visual Component objects but no version definition
```

How to solve this compile error?

Automation Studio V 4.0.29.87.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This a bad setting in Project -> Change Run Time Versions.  With this bug the Visual components are not set.   To Fix set the version you desire.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, really!!